# Pronoun usage - subjective /objective/possessive

Tags: pronouns

> The fact that John was a good student resulted in *his/him* having many offers for the job.

Which one should be used and why?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but the possessive form is being used less and less these days.

If you take a look at [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his%20saying%2C%20him%20saying&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20saying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chim%20saying%3B%2Cc0) you can see how the use of *him saying* vs *his saying* evolved over time.

That being said, some English teachers often still consider the non-possessive form as incorrect, though I think it is widely accepted nowadays. So to answer your question: both options can be used and they are both correct.